# Visual artifact at high browser zoom levels

Tags: bug, status-deferred, design

I found this while trying to get a closer look at the house in the logo.

[image: Screenshot displaying artifact]

To reproduce:

1. Open a browser window to http://diy.stackexchange.com
2. Zoom in until there's a horizontal scrollbar displayed.
3. Scroll to the right.

This occurs in both Firefox 3.6.14 and Chrome 9.0.597.107 on Linux (Fedora 14).  Also IE 8.0.6001.18702, Firefox 3.6.14 and Chrome 9.0.597.107 on Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Niall, I can reproduce this. This is because browsers don't re-paint and re-tile the background image (the white glow on top) and the inset box-shadow I set for the body on page zoom. But if you resize the browser window a bit it then re-renders the page fine.

I'm not sure if I see this as a real problem, since you'd have to zoom a few levels to get to that. Even then, it's not hindering the readability of the site, for those who read web sites with page zoom on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; I thought it was odd, and didn't notice it on a quick sampling of other sites.  So... mark it as _status-no-big-deal_... :)